# Retrofit doesn't call onReponse and onFailure

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

In my case I have used retrofit to contact with rest api. Unfortunately when i start it never reach onResponse and onFailure state neither. I checked in debug line after line and it looks that he proceed to line: `call.enqueue(new Callback<Api>() {`  and subsequently it goes back to the beginning loop, proceed again to the same line and skip two statements, finally finish whole method. Of course the question is why?

```
public void ApiHit(String[] tags) {

    //retrofit
    TagApi tagApi = NetworkService.retrofit.create(TagApi.class);

    //recieve words from searchview, divide and put into string array
    for (int i=0; i < tags.length; i++){

        Call<Api> call = tagApi.getTasks(tags[i]);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Api>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Api> call, Response<Api> response) {


                //recieve possible tags for one word and put it into list
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {
                    listTags.add(new RowModel(response.body().getResults().get(i).getTag(), response.body().getResults().get(i).getAbsRelevance()));

                }

                //sort whole list
                Collections.sort(listTags);

                //add first tags to list
                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                    listTagsFinal.add(new RowModel(listTags.get(y).getName(), listTags.get(y).getPosition()));
                }

                if (!isTagognizerTag) {
                    listTagsFinal.add(new RowModel("tagognizer", 23477853));
                    isTagognizerTag = true;
                }

                //add rest tags to list
                for (int y = 3; y < listTags.size(); y++) {
                    listTagsRest.add(new RowModel(listTags.get(y).getName(), listTags.get(y).getPosition()));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Api> call, Throwable t) {
            }

        });

    }
    //final sort
    Collections.sort(listTagsFinal);
    Collections.sort(listTagsRest);

    for (int y = 0; listTagsFinal.size() < 30; y++) {
        listTagsFinal.add(new RowModel(listTagsRest.get(y).getName(), listTagsRest.get(y).getPosition()));
    }

}
```

and I call it in in the same class (mainactivity) in onCreate - when user accept inputed text into searchView:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        listTags = new ArrayList<>();
        listTagsFinal = new ArrayList<>();
        listTagsRest = new ArrayList<>();

        //set Proxima Bold font on top textview
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/proximabold.ttf");
        tvTop.setTypeface(typeface);


        //search text handler
        svSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                result = query.split(",?\\ ");
                for (int x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                    //  Log.d("ciacho", result[x] + "\n");

                }
                ApiHit(result);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //This is your adapter that will be filtered
                return false;
            }
        });


    }
```

thats my simple model class:

```
public class RowModel implements Comparable<RowModel>{

    private String name;
    private float position;

    public float getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(float position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public RowModel(String name, float position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RowModel rowModel) {
        float comparePosition = ((RowModel) rowModel).getPosition();


        return (int) (this.position- comparePosition);
    }
```

and default class to communicate with rest:

```
public class Api {

    @SerializedName("geo")
    @Expose
    private List<Float> geo = null;
    @SerializedName("rank")
    @Expose
    private int rank;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> results = null;
    @SerializedName("tag")
    @Expose
    private String tag;
    @SerializedName("tagExists")
    @Expose
    private boolean tagExists;

    public List<Float> getGeo() {
        return geo;
    }

    public void setGeo(List<Float> geo) {
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public boolean isTagExists() {
        return tagExists;
    }

    public void setTagExists(boolean tagExists) {
        this.tagExists = tagExists;
    }

}
```

and implementation of my retrofit class:

```
public class NetworkService {

    public static final Interceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    public static final OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.xxx.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();
```

and last class:

```
public interface TagApi {


    @GET("/tag/{tagId}")
    Call<Api> getTasks(
            @Path("tagId") String tagId);


}
```

Comment: may be your response not successfull..

Comment: you can check it by...  `if (response.isSuccessful)` // do sumthing else { // do another part.. your app enters here

Comment: check your models..

Comment: but if reponse is unsuccessfull should he call straightaway onFailure ?

Comment: no..onfailure is not called in that case..it just throws not successfull...its a method in retrofit..

Comment: use it onResponse to handle responses

Comment: If neither `onResponse` nor `onFailure` are called, then you've probably configured Retrofit incorrectly and there is an exception in the LogCat explaining where you went wrong. Please include the code you used to set up retrofit.

Comment: @W.K.S i have added implementation of retrofit

Comment: @ArminOrlik You're missing a `/` at the end of `"http://api.xxx.com"`

Comment: @W.K.S just take a look on my last class...

Answer (score 0):

In Retrofit 2, you should add a `/` at the end of the baseUrl:

```
public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.xxx.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();
```

and you should not put a `/` in front of the endpoint path:

```
public interface TagApi {
    @GET("tag/{tagId}")
    Call<Api> getTasks(
            @Path("tagId") String tagId);

}
```

Have a look at the example [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: unfortunately your change doesn't solve the problem:(

Comment: Can you check your logcat to see if there are any relevant exceptions?

Comment: yeap he throw me this exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 what is quite obvious because he skip crucial part of code which is encapsulated in onResponse part

Comment: Sorry, I mean is there an exception when Retrofit is being set up

Comment: no unfortunately there is no error, and i don't know how to force it to throw me any exception or log...

Answer (score 0):

[call.enqueue](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) is an asynchronous operation, first FOR loop will continue to run after call.enqueue. If you want to block till response is received you need use synchronous [call.execute](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute--)

If you comment below FOR loop and put a breakpoint inside onResponse(), I think you should see breakpoint is hit.

```
for (int y = 0; listTagsFinal.size() < 30; y++) {
    listTagsFinal.add(new RowModel(listTagsRest.get(y).getName(), listTagsRest.get(y).getPosition()));
}
```